# Got an error popup in eclipse which says "Transfer error:read only file system"

Tags: android, eclipse, sd-card

I am an android newbie and am attempting to display an offline map via android Eclipse.

When I try to push a map file onto the android SD card in File explorer I get an error right at the beginning which says : 
`transfer error:read only file system, Failed to push selection: Read-only file system`

I checked that the file's read-only attribute is not set.

Any clues regarding what might be going wrong ?

Comment: Did you try running Eclipse as Administrator?

Comment: yes i've tried that. Still the same error

Comment: Which directory on the droid did you try to save your file to? Some are indeed read-only.